# div height to fill the whole page

Tags: html, css

I have a div and I want it to fill the whole page without any horizontal or vertical scrolling.

The html is like:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
    </div>
</body>
```

and the css like:

```
body{
  background: #222;
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container{
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:20px;
  width:800px;
  background: rgba(20,20,20,0.2);
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Normally with `vh` it works, but because of some padding applied on container it doesn't work. So what technique can I use to solve this problem?

[The JSFiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/blaisemugisha/gdohu3g1/)

Answer (score 4):

Try using [`box-sizing: border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) on your `.container` element. Doing so will have the padding and border of an element included with width and height assignments.

```css
.container {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 800px;
    background: rgba(20,20,20,0.2);
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with [the way that css adds the padding to the height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box_model) to calculate the total height. There's one quick and flexible fix for all of your elements though, as explained in [Paul Irish's box-sizing](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/):

```
/* apply a natural box layout model to all elements, but allowing components to change */
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not Sure Will this help you but you can give it a try-

give position relative to your body and position fixed to your div.container with width 100% and height 100%.

```
body{
    background: #222;
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    position:relative;
}
.container{
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    background: red;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This could be a possible solution if instead the content was set to the width the OP was using and also centered the element.

Answer (score 1):

[Box-sizing FTW!](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/) If you need to *include* the padding as part of the elements dimensions then `box-sizing: border-box` is your only hope.

**FWIW** you should be aware that [Viewport Units are not fully supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) so if you need something more cross-browser you can easily avoid using `100vh` by using `100%` instead.

E.G:

```css
html, body {
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
}
body{
    background: #222;
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
}
.container{
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:20px;
    width:800px;
    background: red;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

</div>
```